# Android Browser call my application and I want to return result

Tags: android

this my scenario.

A browser (Chrome, Firefox...) call my application with my content scheme
myscheme://urltoparse

In my app I would like to return to the brother with a new url (fail or success) on the same page.

```
//For the moment I Just arrive to create a new page in the browser
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://mysite/fail.html"));
startActivity(intent); //create new page

finish();
```

If someone has an idea...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then one application called your application (via the browser) and you want to return an answer to the app?
The way to do this is the application that called your application will use the function:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult (i, 1);
```

And you will use:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent ();
returnIntent.putExtra ("result", result);
setResult (RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish ();
```

The application that called you realize the callback:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
 }
}//onActivityResult
```

If you meant something else, please explain and I'll try to help.

Comment: The applications which call my Application are Google Chrome, Firefox... with url "myscheme://urltoparse".

Comment: If your application was called from the browser, then you can not go back to it with data.
You can open a browser from your app with a specific url you want.
But if your application was called from web application then there is a management session and you can go back with your own data.

Comment: What do you call "web application" ? Chrome Firefox ?

Comment: A web application is any software that runs in a web browser. It is created in a browser-supported programming language (such as the combination of JavaScript, HTML and CSS) and relies on a web browser to render the application.
In this case the application manages sessions and can access the users / other applications, and to interact with them, send them parameters and to know to get information back.